# Adding an object of one class to an object of another class and checking for duplicates in Python

Tags: python

I have to create two classes Player and Group. 
Class Player has attributes name and level. After an instance of Player is created an unique identifier is created within the range of 0 to 99.

Class Group has attribute name. After an instance of Group is created an unique groupIdentifier is created within the range of 0 to 20. In the class Group I need to create a method called addPlayer to add an instance of class Player and check if the instance to be added is duplicate or not. The addPlayer method returns the unique identifier of the Player which is added to it. I have the following code:

```
class Player(object): 
    identifier =0  
    def __init__(self,name, level=""):
        self.name = name
        self.level =level
        self.identifier += 1
        if(len(self.name) < 1):
            raise ValueError("Name.__init__:  is empty")

        if(self.identifier>=99):
            raise ValueError("Identifier.__init__:  exceeds 99")

class Group(object): 
    groupIdentifier =0  
    def __init__(self,name, player=[]):

        self.name = name
        self.player = player
        self.groupIdentifier += 1
        if(len(self.name) < 1):
            raise ValueError("Name.__init__:  is empty")

        if(self.groupIdentifier>20):
            raise ValueError("GroupIdentifier.__init__:  exceeds 20")


    def addPlayer(self, myPlayer): 
        if myPlayeris None:
            raise ValueError("myPlayer:  is empty")

        for x in range(len(self.player)):
            if self.player[x]==(myPlayer):
               raise ValueError("Player:  is duplicate")

        self.participant.append(myPlayer)
        return self.player.identifier
```

Can you please suggest the changes I need to make in my code to meet the requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the class attribute to give identifiers to players (and groups!), not instance attributes:

```
class Player(object): 
    identifier = 0  
    def __init__(self,name, level=""):
        self.name = name
        self.level =level
        # identifier belong to the class not an instance of it!
        # change in Group as well!
        self.identifier == Player.identifier
        Player.identifier += 1
        if(len(self.name) < 1): # can be 'if not self.name'
            raise ValueError("Name.__init__:  is empty")

        if(self.identifier>=99):
            raise ValueError("Identifier.__init__:  exceeds 99")
```

Override `__eq__` in `Player` to be able to compare players by their identifier:

```
class Player(object): 
    # ... init code
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Player):
            # other object is a Player instance with the same identifier
            return self.identifier == other.identifier
        return False
```

You may also want to use `self.players` (plural) in `Group` to mark the fact it's a `list` of multiple `Player` instances.

Now change the player comparing bit in `Group` and use the `in` keyword:

```
if myPlayer in self.players:
    raise ValueError("Player:  is duplicate")
```

After changes:

```
class Player(object): 
    identifier = 0  
    def __init__(self,name, level=""):
        self.name = name
        self.level =level
        self.identifier += Player.identifier
        Player.identifier += 1
        if not self.name:
            raise ValueError("Name.__init__:  is empty")

        if(self.identifier>=99):
            raise ValueError("Identifier.__init__:  exceeds 99")

    def __eq__(self, other):
    if isinstance(other, Player):
        # other object is a Player instance with the same identifier
        return self.identifier == other.identifier
    return False

class Group(object): 
    groupIdentifier = 0  

    def __init__(self,name, players=[]):

        self.name = name
        self.players = players
        self.groupIdentifier = Group.groupIdentifier
        Group.groupIdentifier += 1
        if not self.name:
            raise ValueError("Name.__init__:  is empty")

        if(self.groupIdentifier>20):
            raise ValueError("GroupIdentifier.__init__:  exceeds 20")


    def addPlayer(self, myPlayer): 
        if myPlayer is None:
            raise ValueError("myPlayer:  is empty")

        if myPlayer in self.players:
            raise ValueError("Player:  is duplicate")

        # removed participant, as it is unclear where it's coming from
        # if you need it - add it to __init__
        self.players.append(myPlayer)
        return myPlayer.identifier
```